# Oracle 11g Report Problem

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Hey friends i am using Oracle 11G. I wanted to generate reports for printing , SO i write this script

```
rem Employee Salary Report

set headsep !

ttitle 'Salary Report'
btitle 'From Employees'

column employee_id format 999.99
column first_name format a20
column last_name format a20
column Salary format 999.99

break on employee_id skip 1 on report

set linesize 80
set pagesize 5
set newpage 0
set feedback off

set pause 'More...'
set pause on

spool activity.lst

select employee_id,first_name,last_name,salary from Employees order by  employee_id ;

spool off
```

When running this script oracle gives

```
line 3: SQLPLUS Command Skipped: set headsep !
line 15: SQLPLUS Command Skipped: set linesize 80
line 16: SQLPLUS Command Skipped: set pagesize 5
line 17: SQLPLUS Command Skipped: set newpage 0
```

and then it executes query and gives output. But my report doesn't include any title in it.Means reports is not generated properly. It just simply executes the select query and gives an output which is not a report.

Comment: What are you running the script in ? SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, TOAD ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a question?

What you show us looks very much like the output we would expect if your script was run from the SQL Worksheet in Oracle SQL Developer.

Those commands that are being skipped are specific to SQL*Plus, and are not supported in SQL Developer (at least, in the version I'm running).

To get a formatted report produced by SQL*Plus, I would run the sqlplus executable from the OS e.g.

```
> $ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus /
SQL> @/home/spencer7593/myreport.sql
SQL> exit
>
```

I'm not sure that answers a question, since I don't know what your question was.